realloc(): invalid old size and Aborted (core dumped) when using realloc and free in a while loop
I am working on a program that uses a linked list implemented as
typedef struct Node{
    char* word;
    int freq;
    struct Node *next;
}Node;

typedef struct {
    Node* head;

}LL;

and have functions
void add_Node(LL* list, char* word, int freq){
  Node* newNode = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
  if(newNode == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "not able to create node\n");
    return;
  }
  
  newNode->word = strdup(word);
  if(newNode->word == NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "can't allocate mem for word\n");
    free(newNode);
    return;
  }

  newNode -> freq = freq;
  newNode->next = NULL;

  if(list->head == NULL){
    list -> head = newNode;
  }
  else{
    Node* current = list->head;
    while(current->next != NULL){
      current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = newNode;
  }
  //return newNode;
}

void addFreq(LL* list, char* word){
  if(word == NULL){
    return;
  }

  Node* current = list->head;
  while(current != NULL){
    if(strcmp(current->word, word) == 0){
      current->freq++;
      return;
    }

    current = current->next;
  }
  add_Node(list, word, 1);
}

void destroyLL(LL* list){
  if(list == NULL){
    return;
  }

  Node* current = list->head;
  Node* next;
  while (current != NULL){
    next = current ->next;
    free(current->word);
    free(current);
    current = next;
  }

  list->head = NULL;
  free(list);
}  //clears the linked list so it can be used again

Im my main function I have nested while loops that parse a file with a word on each line and store a word of specific length in the linked list, as such:
//assume all needed header files are included
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  LL* list = (LL*)malloc(sizeof(LL));
  //list->head = NULL;  
  
  //file meant to be parsed opened using fopen(/*name*/, "r"), nothing went wrong here
  input = fopen(argv[1], "r");  //file for the inputs
  
  char target[100];
  int length;
  int target_freq;
  
  while(fgets(target, sizeof(target), input) != NULL){ //gets inputs from input file
    
    if(sscanf(target, "%d %d", &length, &target_freq)==2){
      
      char word[100];
        while(fgets(word, sizeof(word), shake_txt) != NULL){ //parses the file of words
          if(strlen(word) == length+1){
          addFreq(list, word);   //adds 1 to the freq field of the node, if it does not exist, add the node
        }
      }
      sortLL(list);
      printf("%s", findWord(list, target_freq));
    }
    destroyLL(list);
    LL* list = (LL*)realloc(list,sizeof(LL));
  }
  //assume files are properly closed
}

After I run the program only the first iteration of the while loop runs, followed by the error message
Bard: malloc.c:2868: mremap_chunk: Assertion `((size + offset) & (GLRO (dl_pagesize) - 1)) == 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

Anyone knows how to fix? Thanks in advance.
I tried replacing the destroyLL(list); with clearLL(list);, but I got the message
realloc(): invalid old size
Aborted (core dumped

here is clearLL
void clearLL(LL* list){
  if(list == NULL || list -> head == NULL){
    return;
  }

  Node* current = list->head;
  Node* next;

  while(current != NULL){
    next = current->next;
    free(current->word);
    free(current);
    current = next; 
  }
  list->head = NULL;
}

Edit:
After following Paddy's suggestions, my destroy function now looks like
void destroyLL(LL* list){
  clearLL(list);
  free(list);
}

and I have uncommented the list->head = NULL; line.
now my main function looks like
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  LL* list = (LL*)malloc(sizeof(LL));
  list->head = NULL;  

  //file meant to be parsed opened using fopen(/*name*/, "r"), nothing went wrong here
  input = fopen(argv[1], "r");  //file for the inputs

  char target[100];
  int length;
  int target_freq;

  while(fgets(target, sizeof(target), input) != NULL){ //gets inputs from input file

    if(sscanf(target, "%d %d", &length, &target_freq)==2){

      char word[100];
        while(fgets(word, sizeof(word), shake_txt) != NULL){ //parses the file of words
          if(strlen(word) == length+1){
          addFreq(list, word);   //adds 1 to the freq field of the node, if it does not exist, add the node
        }
      }
      sortLL(list);
      printf("%s", findWord(list, target_freq));
    }
    destroyLL(list);
    list = (LL*)malloc(sizeof(LL));
  }
  //assume files are properly closed
}

After compiling and running, I got the error Segmentation fault (core dumped) after the first iteration of the while loop running(it printed an output). Runninf valgrind with --leak-check=full gave me
==647== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==647== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==647== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==647== Command: ./Bard simple-input.txt
==647== 
father
==647== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==647==    at 0x108DED: sortLL (in /home/codio/workspace/Bard/Bard)
==647==    by 0x109025: main (in /home/codio/workspace/Bard/Bard)
==647== 
==647== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==647==    at 0x108E55: findWord (in /home/codio/workspace/Bard/Bard)
==647==    by 0x10903C: main (in /home/codio/workspace/Bard/Bard)
==647== 
==647== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==647==    at 0x108E7B: clearLL (in /home/codio/workspace/Bard/Bard)
==647==    by 0x108EE7: destroyLL (in /home/codio/workspace/Bard/Bard)
==647==    by 0x10905F: main (in /home/codio/workspace/Bard/Bard)
==647== 
(null)(null)(null)(null)(null)==647== 
==647== HEAP SUMMARY:
==647==     in use at exit: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==647==   total heap usage: 9,706 allocs, 9,705 frees, 165,480 bytes allocated
==647== 
==647== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==647==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==647==    by 0x109069: main (in /home/codio/workspace/Bard/Bard)
==647== 
==647== LEAK SUMMARY:
==647==    definitely lost: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==647==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==647==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==647==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==647==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==647== 
==647== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==647== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==647== ERROR SUMMARY: 16 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

Edit 2:
for those interested, here is findWord
char* findWord(LL* list, int freqRank){
  Node* current = list->head;
  int count = 0;

  while(current != NULL){
    if(count == freqRank){
      return current->word;
    }
    count++;
    
    current = current->next;
  }
  return NULL;
}

and sortLL, which uses merge sort:
Node* merge(Node* left, Node* right){
  Node* result = NULL;

  if(left == NULL){
    return right;
  }
  if(right == NULL){
    return left;
  }

  if(compareNode(left, right) <= 0){
    result = left;
    result->next = merge(left->next, right);
  }
  else{
    result = right;
    result->next = merge(left, right->next);
  }

  return result;
}

void mergeSort(Node** headRef){
  Node* head = *headRef;
  Node* right;
  Node* left;

  if (head == NULL || head->next == NULL){
    return;
  }

  Node* slow = head;
  Node* fast = head->next;

  while(fast != NULL){
    fast = fast->next;
    if(fast != NULL){
      slow = slow->next;
      fast = fast->next;
    }
  }

  left = head;
  right = slow->next;
  slow->next = NULL;

  mergeSort(&left);
  mergeSort(&right);

  *headRef = merge(left, right);
}

void sortLL(LL* list){
  if(list == NULL || list->head ==NULL || list->head->next ==NULL){
    return;
  }

  mergeSort(&(list->head));
}


Edit 3: Following @Paddy's suggestion, not my main looks like:
//assume all needed header files are included
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  LL* list = (LL*)malloc(sizeof(LL));
  //list->head = NULL;  

  //file meant to be parsed opened using fopen(/*name*/, "r"), nothing went wrong here
  input = fopen(argv[1], "r");  //file for the inputs

  char target[100];
  int length;
  int target_freq;

  while(fgets(target, sizeof(target), input) != NULL){ //gets inputs from input file

    if(sscanf(target, "%d %d", &length, &target_freq)==2){

      char word[100];
        while(fgets(word, sizeof(word), shake_txt) != NULL){ //parses the file of words
          if(strlen(word) == length+1){
          addFreq(list, word);   //adds 1 to the freq field of the node, if it does not exist, add the node
        }
      }
      sortLL(list);
      printf("%s", findWord(list, target_freq));
    }
    clearLL(list);
  }
  //assume files are properly closed
}

It outputs
father    // <--the first output
(null)(null)(null)(null)(null)  // <--the remaining outputs from the remaining inputs

Here is what I got from valgrind:
==686== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==686== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==686== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==686== Command: ./Bard simple-input.txt
==686== 
father
(null)(null)(null)(null)(null)==686== 
==686== HEAP SUMMARY:
==686==     in use at exit: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==686==   total heap usage: 9,700 allocs, 9,699 frees, 165,432 bytes allocated
==686== 
==686== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
==686==    at 0x4C2FB0F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==686==    by 0x108F27: main (in /home/codio/workspace/Bard/Bard)
==686== 
==686== LEAK SUMMARY:
==686==    definitely lost: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==686==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==686==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==686==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==686==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==686== 
==686== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==686== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0

Edit 4: The reason why it was printing null was because for some reason nothing was added to the linked list on the second iteration and later. Anyone got any suggestions?

Why did you comment-out list->head = NULL; in main? That line is very important. Without it, your object is uninitialized.

destroyLL(list);     LL* list = (LL*)realloc(list,sizeof(LL)); I'm afraid there are multiple problems with those 2 lines from the end of your while loop.

I'd suggest looking at valgrind, and seeing if it says that you have a use-after-free or write out of bounds.

Change realloc() to malloc(). You've already freed what you're trying to realloc: this makes no sense.

Or, instead of valgrind, compile with -g -fsanitize=address,unknown -O0. It can be a bit finer grained. It will possibly stop exactly on the line of code that is the issue.

@CraigEstey what would be the command to do that? cc -o -g -fsanitize=address,unknown -O0 Bard Bard.c gives me the error cc: error: unrecognized argument to -fsanitize= option: ‘unknown’

destroyLL frees everything that list points to, that could be OK. LL* list creates a brand new local variable named list that hides the one that you have been using (and that still exists) while in this scope. realloc(list, passes an invalid value to realloc (the visible list is uninitialized at this point). The immediate end of the loop ends the lifetime of the most local list, leaking the memory that would have been allocated if it was a valid realloc call. You wanted destroyLL(list); list = malloc(sizeof(LL)); here.

You need -fsanitize=address,undefined. Not unknown.

@paddy @user207421 I have changed the realloc to malloc and uncommented the list->head = NULL; line. I am getting Bard: malloc.c:2868: mremap_chunk: Assertion ((size + offset) & (GLRO (dl_pagesize) - 1)) == 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)` after the first iteration.

@AviBerger so I changed LL* list = (LL*)realloc(list,sizeof(LL)); to list = malloc(sizeof(LL));, the first iteration still works, but now I am getting the error munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer Aborted (core dumped)

After the first iteration of what?

@user207421 of the outer while loop

Do you mean the while (fgets(...)) loop? Please be specific. We're trying to help but you're not making it easy. Can you also state at which line of code you get this? And BTW what is shake_text?

OT: Why do you want list to be dynamic allocated? The LL type is just a single pointer and you never allocate more than 1 instance so dynamic allocation seems to make thinge more complicated than needed. In start of main just do LL list = { 0 }; and then use &list when passing a pointer.

You do want to use the sanitizer. It will hopefully show you where the first error occurs.

@user207421 the while(fgets(target, sizeof(target), input) != NULL){ loop

Aside: you have your abstract data type LL. All operations on it are abstracted away to functions, which is good—except for (the most important) one: creation, which is bad.Write LL* createLL()  —and it must initialise head. Do not call malloc realloc or delete anywhere except these dedicated functions.

And what is shake_text? 2nd time of asking. The code you post here must compile. It doesn't.

@user207421 sorry for the delay, shake_text is a file with a single word on each line. The words can repeat. It is the file opened before the line input = fopen(argv[1], "r");  //file for the inputs. Assume nothing went wrong here.

@n.m.couldbeanAI thank you for the advice, I will keep that in mind in my futre projects. For now I do not want to make things more complicated than it already is.

Have you considered that your sortLL and/or findWord functions (which you did not show) might be broken? Have you tried commenting them out and seeing if your program stops crashing? A common way to investigate a program with a repeatable problem is to remove parts of it until it starts working, then add parts back in until it breaks.

This makes things simpler not more complicated. That's why this approach was invented in the first place.

My answer was wrong. I said that the "malloc" version would work, but left out the important bit that @n.m.couldbeanAI is talking about -- forgetting to initialize head. See how easy it is to do that, and why having a function is useful? Even I forgot, immediately after telling you about it. Because I never actually intended you do select that when I was using it as a transition into what you should do which is just call clearLL. I'll update the answer accordingly.

At the top of main, you allocate a new list but do not initialize it:
LL* list = (LL*)malloc(sizeof(LL));
//list->head = NULL;  

For unknown reasons, you commented-out the initialization. As a result, the value of head is indeterminate and your program has undefined behavior.
To fix that, uncomment the offending line:
list->head = NULL;


Later, when you attempt to destroy your list and allocate a new one, you're trying to realloc a dangling pointer.
destroyLL(list);
LL* list = (LL*)realloc(list,sizeof(LL));

Except it's not a dangling pointer -- it's an uninitialized pointer because here a new local variable named list is being defined.
Changing this to malloc as you attempted still doesn't fix the issue because the list variable belonging to the larger scope of main is hidden by this local variable.
// Wrong:
destroyLL(list);
LL* list = (LL*)malloc(sizeof(LL));  // <-- Not the 'list' variable you think it is

The above allocates memory to the while-loop's 'list' variable, and then immediately leaks it when that variable goes out of scope. The original list variable remains unchanged.
This would technically work:
// Ugly:
destroyLL(list);
list = (LL*)malloc(sizeof(LL));
list->head = NULL;

But that's unnecessary, and it also assumes allocation succeeded. In fact, there's no need to free list and allocate another at all. Doing this would be considered bad practice.
You can instead just "clear" your list, by replacing these lines with:
clearLL(list);


Side-note 1: Since the clearLL function has a lot in common with destroyLL, you can re-use code by defining destroyLL as:
void destroyLL(LL* list){
    clearLL(list);
    free(list);
}

Side-note 2: You have all these functions to manipulate your list, but you require the list itself be created manually. This is not good practice. You should consider symmetry of an interface. You already have a destroyLL function, so you ought to have a matching createLL function:
LL* createLL(){
    LL* list = malloc(sizeof(LL));
    if (list) list->head = NULL;
    return list;
}

Doing this makes for cleaner code, and also avoids mistakes (like forgetting to initialize head). It also allows for future changes to your implementation without requiring changes to all the code that uses it.

Thank you. I have made the changes you have suggested. Good news is there is no seg fault anymore. Bad news is instead of seg fault after the first output it is just (null)(null)(null)... repeating based on the remaining number of inputs from the inoput file.

Well, now it's time to use your debugger and investigate why the behavior of your program differs from what you expect. Start by storing the result of findWord in a variable and checking for NULL before you try to print it. Then, look at the findWord function and ask yourself what actual count it's testing. Is it testing the actual word frequency stored on a node? Or is it testing something else?

the reason why it was printing null was because nothing was being added to the linked list on the second and later iterations
